# Error: quota exceeded (DNS resolutions : per day)

Tags: node.js, firebase, dns, google-cloud-storage

I have a Firebase app with a Cloud Function that generates some thumbnails when an image is uploaded to a particular bucket.

I keep getting these errors, pretty much nonstop:
[image]

**My question is**, and granted I am somewhat new to the Google Cloud Platform, how many times does DNS resolution happen? Does it happen on any upload and downloaded between Firebase and Google Cloud Storage?

All my operations are between Firebase and Google Cloud Storage (i.e. - download from bucket, resize in temp space, and upload back to bucket), and I have a check to make sure not to automatically return if an image begins with 'thumb_' to avoid infinite loop.

That being said, I believe I have this error because initially I accidentally did get myself into an infinite loop and blow out my quota.

Here is some more info about DNS resolutions, I'm not entirely sure how to interpret it but it appears 'DNS resolutions per 100 seconds' is exceeded, but 'DNS resolutions per day is not'

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the quota limts are `40,000 per 100 seconds` Either you are having so many calls, or there is some bug in your code which might be making too many calls unknowingly.